# How to send an email using Gmail's SMTP without writing it in Sent Mail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I would like to send a message using Gmail's SMTP without storing the message in the Sent Mail folder. I'm aware that SMTP doesn't write anything in the IMAP folders, but Gmail has different behaviour and it *autosync* the messages sent through SMTP in the IMAP folders.

Is there any way (flag, header, etc.) to avoid this auto sync behaviour when sending and email using Gmail's SMTP?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could just delete the message from your sent folder right after you send it.

Access the sent folder and retrieve the latest message sent. Then set the flag of that message to delete

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

Then close the folder

```
sentFolder.close(true);
```

Closing the folder will delete the flagged message from it. Code examples are in java, if you're writing in it.

Other than manually deleting the message, I don't think there is a way to disable this action.

Comment: Thank you @connorp for your answer. That is what I did. FYI flagging a message as deleted in a folder different than `spam` or `trash` archives the message. So to delete the message after sending it through SMTP, I connect to send folder, then move the message to the trash, flag it as deleted, and then close  the folder.